# In python bytecode what does fast stand for?

Tags: python, bytecode, python-internals

As in `LOAD_FAST`. `LOAD_CONST` is obvious. Or maybe fast just stands for 'fast' and is a.. quick way to load a local variable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`LOAD_FAST` is used for *local variables*, accessing the value in an array by index. This is faster than accessing variable values in a dictionary, by name, with `LOAD_NAME` (which searches through all scopes, from the current function object outwards).

In Python 2, function locals could either be *optimised*, by using an array, or locals could be dynamically added and required the use of `LOAD_NAME`. If you used the [`exec` statement](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#exec) with `locals()`, then locals can't be optimized because `exec` might add arbitrary local variables, and Python can't know if they are local or should be treated as globals:

```
>>> def optimised(bar): return bar
...
>>> dis.dis(optimised)
  1           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (bar)
              3 RETURN_VALUE
>>> def not_optimised(bar):
...     exec bar
...     return spam  # global, or local? Python can't know
...
>>> not_optimised("spam = 42")
42
>>> not_optimised("ham = 'no spam!'")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in not_optimised
NameError: name 'spam' is not defined
>>> dis.dis(not_optimised)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (bar)
              3 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              6 DUP_TOP
              7 EXEC_STMT

  3           8 LOAD_NAME                0 (spam)
             11 RETURN_VALUE
```

This is also reflected in the `function.__code__.co_flags` flag variable, the [`inspect.CO_OPTIMIZED` bit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.CO_OPTIMIZED) is set:

```
>>> import inspect
>>> bool(optimised.__code__.co_flags & inspect.CO_OPTIMIZED)
True
>>> bool(not_optimised.__code__.co_flags & inspect.CO_OPTIMIZED)
False
```

In Python 3, with the `exec` statement removed, locals are always optimised, and you no longer can set locals dynamically.

`LOAD_NAME` is still used in Python 3, but never in critical code. The bytecode generated for creating a class object uses `LOAD_NAME` to access the `__annotations__` mapping when you use a [variable annotation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/), for example:

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis("class Foo:\n    bar: int\n")
  1           0 LOAD_BUILD_CLASS
              2 LOAD_CONST               0 (<code object Foo at 0x10e050df0, file "<dis>", line 1>)
              4 LOAD_CONST               1 ('Foo')
              6 MAKE_FUNCTION            0
              8 LOAD_CONST               1 ('Foo')
             10 CALL_FUNCTION            2
             12 STORE_NAME               0 (Foo)
             14 LOAD_CONST               2 (None)
             16 RETURN_VALUE

Disassembly of <code object Foo at 0x10e050df0, file "<dis>", line 1>:
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (__name__)
              2 STORE_NAME               1 (__module__)
              4 LOAD_CONST               0 ('Foo')
              6 STORE_NAME               2 (__qualname__)
              8 SETUP_ANNOTATIONS

  2          10 LOAD_NAME                3 (int)
             12 LOAD_NAME                4 (__annotations__)
             14 LOAD_CONST               1 ('bar')
             16 STORE_SUBSCR
             18 LOAD_CONST               2 (None)
             20 RETURN_VALUE
```